# How to force browser caching of text-file (.ttf)

Tags: php, html, css, browser, server

I am making a website.
at http://snpskollam.cf
and is also experienced on makeing another one at http://chemio.cf
I am facing a problem,
ie. There is a text-file in my server (MontserratRegular.ttf). I linked this file to each and every ".css" of all the pages.
And the problem is that, the browser downloads it for reading on the request for every page. The text-file is about 250KB and the size is a bit large. This may disturb the people with a slow internet connection. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: My website is http://www.snpskollam.cf

Comment: Are you using SASS or Less?, any Code, codeply, jsfiddle etc would be great.

Comment: 250KB is not too large. Please show your code.

Comment: I think you can visit it plz ? snpskollam.cf

Comment: The code is too large

Comment: The font-family property should hold several font names as a "fallback" system, to ensure maximum compatibility between browsers/operating systems. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font with smaller kb or less than 250kb.

Comment: Have you tried to link the font from a CDN into header, in HTML?

Comment: no I will Try can you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your webserver to deliver cache headers. For example, with the apache webserver and mod_expires:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 300 seconds"

  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day 1 hour"
</IfModule>
```

Customize this to your need with ttf files.